# Secure url required in page tab apps, despite sandbox

Tags: facebook, https

We're developing locally a facebook app that should reside in a page tab.

The app is in sandbox mode, so the secure url should not be required - still, the "please update your secure url" message appears.

All work perfectly on the non-tab ("Apps on facebook.com") version, so I'm pretty sure it's a bug/"undocumented feature" and I'm probably gonna get my local apache version to accept secure requests - still, I'd like to know if anyone can figure out something I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable HTTPS on your account while testing? The behaviour before that message was introduced was that the tab wouldn't render link at all if it didn't support HTTPS but you were browsing in HTTPS mode

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. Is that feature documented somewhere? It's a funny behaviour, since I can use my sandboxed standalone apps even when my secure navigation is disabled.

Comment: I thought there was still an interstitial page prompting you to temporarily disable HTTPS, no?

Comment: Nope. Just the standard, "no https lol silly developer" thing.